# Did Elizabeth Warren plagiarize recipes and publish a book called "Pow Wow Chow"?

Tags: united-states, politics

From the [Daily Mall](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2146628/Elizabeth-Warrens-Pow-Wow-Chow-Cherokee-recipes-word-word-COPIES-famous-FRENCH-chefs-techniques.html)

> Massachusetts Democratic Senate candidate Elizabeth Warren is yet again in hot water after new allegations have surfaced that she plagiarized her 'Cherokee' recipes in the book Pow Wow Chow from the New York Times and other publications.

I'm skeptical that

- Elizabeth Warren presented recipes as Cherokee
- Led people to believe those recipes were "handed down from generation to generation"
- These recipes were found elsewhere word-for-word (or in very much the same form)

Comment: Regardless of what you want to ignore, the claim is plagiarism and I'm skeptical.

Comment: @GEdgar I'm not a fan of holding politicians to a different standard than the rest of us. Will this allegation if true damage her career? Probably not, but just because information like this might well be ignored by those who've already come to an opinion on her one way or another doesn't mean that we should only focus on the "damaging" claims to be skeptical about.

Comment: @T.Sar-ReinstateMonica I dare you to come to Houston and try to peddle a NYT recipe for BBQ sauce as Texan and sign your name to it.

Comment: The title should be edited to reflect that the cited claim does _not_ claim that Warren _published_ the book, but rather only that she plagiarized recipes in the book. Either that, or a notable claim needs to be added that claims she actually published the book.

Comment: @Evan Carroll: Texans have no effing idea how to make proper barbecue sauce.  This is the proper way: https://www.atlasobscura.com/articles/cornell-chicken-barbecue-sauce-upstate

Comment: "Lead people to believe" I take it you mean "Led people to believe"?

Comment: The thing about Texans, @jamesqf, is that we know how to make our barbecue good enough that it doesn't need to be slathered with sauce. I grew up eating Texas BBQ, and I don't ever remember eating it with sauce. Pickles, onions, jalapenos, and delicious, juicy, grilled meat. Wait, what did this have to do with Elizabeth Warren?

Comment: @Acccumulation that's why God invented [edit]

Comment: @Cody Gray: Then your version of barbecue is different than any I encountered there.  Which was usually something slathered in tomato-based sauce.  And it has to do with cooking, which is what the question is about, no?

Comment: I'd be skeptical about anything published in the Daily Mail to start with and even more skeptical about a recipe book that purports to be 'Pow Wow Chow' and uses ingredients like 'Wishbone Italian Salad Dressing' and 'Worcestershire sauce' which I very much doubt were available to the Cherokee prior to the 20th century.

Answer (score 42):

The first and most significant error is the incorrect claim that Warren "published" the book, a claim which no one has made other than social media sources. It was actually the "Five Civilized Tribes Museum" that published it. The cookbook was edited by [Warren's cousin](https://web.archive.org/web/20120511094411/http://bostonherald.com/news/us_politics/view.bg?articleid=1061128421), Jayne "Candy" Rowsey [(1932-2002)](https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/14310971/jayne-_candy_-rowsey). Pow Wow Chow is [still available today](http://www.fivetribes.org/Gift%20Shop.html) from the website of the Five Civilized Tribes Museum.

According to a 2012 *Boston Herald* article, Warren's campaign team [cited Candy Rowsey's involvement with the museum as proof](https://web.archive.org/web/20120511094411/http://bostonherald.com/news/us_politics/view.bg?articleid=1061128421) that she was really part Cherokee. The claim that the cookbook contains “recipes passed down through family members" can be sourced to a former museum volunteer quoted in [a subsequent *Herald* article](https://www.bostonherald.com/2012/05/17/pow-wow-factor-elizabeth-warren-touted-native-roots-in-84-cookbook/), as no direct quotation from the cookbook can be found.

Warren was indeed presented as Cherokee in the text of *Pow Wow Chow*. However, there is no text saying that this is Warren's own claim to membership in the Cherokee tribe. Conceivably the tribal affiliation could have been added by her cousin. This two-page spread shows that her cousin appended a tribal affiliation to every contributor.

[image]

On page 156, Candy Rowsey's name appears next to Warren's. On the page opposite is her brother-in-law, Paul Rowsey [(1926-2001)](https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/14310963/paul-edward-rowsey), who is remarkably also listed as Cherokee.

[image]

It is true that these recipes were found nearly word-for-word in earlier sources: in 2012, *Breitbart* observed that [Warren's recipes are identical](https://www.breitbart.com/politics/2012/05/18/did-elizabeth-warren-plagiarize-pow-wow-chow-recipes/) with earlier recipes found in newspapers. However, because relevant sections of the book have not been reproduced, it is unclear if *Pow Wow Chow* actually claims to be "handed down from generation to generation" or if this is simply a collection of recipes contributed by a group of Candy Rowsey's acquaintances. No one has produced a quotation from Warren claiming to have invented or inherited the recipes she contributed. [There is no copyright on recipes](https://lizerbramlaw.com/2015/04/07/copyright-protect-recipes/) so simply copying a recipe from a newspaper, without claiming it to be your own work, does not constitute plagiarism.

Comment: I disagree with the last sentence.  Plagiarism consists in passing off the work of others as your own.  It is irrelevant whether that work was copyrighted, or whether it could be.  The concepts of plagiarism and copyright are completely orthogonal.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103377/discussion-on-answer-by-avery-did-elizabeth-warren-plagiarize-recipes-and-publis).

Comment: Deleted more discussion on the differences between plagiarism and copyright. Take it to chat; it isn't helping answer this question.